# Regex function wont match. How to write correctly

Tags: regex

Trying to create Regex code that starts with @ and then matches any alphanumeric character.

How do I make a code for Regex to match a line that starts with @ and then followed by \w ?

Comment: show what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the following:
`^@\w+`

- The `^` makes sure the string actually starts with the expression that follows.
- We only check for one `@` character so we just place that there without anything else.
- The `\w` includes all alphanumeric characters and underscores.
- The `+` ensures there is at least one of the preceding token (at least one alphanumeric character in your case).

You should really try to attempt to learn expressions on your own though and try before you ask. I recommend this website to learn from: https://regexr.com/

Comment: Thank you, yes I am trying. My issues is specifically with grouping them because I want to use it match @ on its own and also this.

Comment: Can you explain in your post why exactly do you want this behavior?